# Azure Functions live event stream is not working

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have deployed a new Azure Functions based on the template - HttpTrigger-CSharp. 
It works fine whenever i invoke it from the webUI or from Postman.

However, the live event stream is not working as expected. I don't see any statistics being populated in the live event stream - everything is zero.

Is there anything which need to be done / configuration / etc?

Thanks,
Aries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring), "there is a known issue that may cause your data to fail to be populated. If you experience this, you may need to close the browser tab containing the live event stream and then click live event stream again to allow it to properly populate your event stream data".

As for the question, no this works out of the box, if it doesn't try closing the browser, opening Azure Portal, then navigating to the Function blade, click Monitor, **wait for it to fully load**, and then click `Live event stream`.

Also, this may not work, if you've created your function recently, just try to wait 5 minutes and try again.

Comment: Yes, i have tried this also without any success. It is still showing all zero. I think there is no problem with the loading, since the UI  was loaded. All the bars are working, the time ticker is moving, etc. Only the data is not being populated.

Comment: try creating another function and see if it works for that function, I've had no issues with live event stream what so ever.

Comment: well, the only idea i have at this point, create a new function app and try creating functions there, also, which pricing tier are you using?

Comment: If you continue to have issues please log an issue here in our repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions/issues with all the relevant details. Thanks.

Comment: I have created a totally new function app collection, and the live event stream works. Thanks a lot for the reply guys.